# Fundamental misunderstanding of MongoDB indices

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So, I read the following definition of indexes from [MongoDB Docs][1].

> Indexes support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. Without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match the query statement. If an appropriate index exists for a query, MongoDB can use the index to limit the number of documents it must inspect.
>
> Indexes are special data structures that store a small portion of the
>   collection’s data set in an easy to traverse form. The index stores
>   the value of a specific field or set of fields, ordered by the value
>   of the field. The ordering of the index entries supports efficient
>   equality matches and range-based query operations. In addition,
>   MongoDB can return sorted results by using the ordering in the index.

I have a sample database with a collection called *pets*. *Pets* have the following structure.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(123abc123abc)
    "name": "My pet's name"
}
```

I created an index on the *name* field using the following code.

```
db.pets.createIndex({"name":1})
```

What I expect is that the documents in the collection, *pets*, will be indexed in ascending order based on the *name* field during queries. The result of this index can potentially reduce the overall query time, especially if a query is strategically structured with available indices in mind. Under that assumption, the following query should return all *pets* sorted by *name* in ascending order, but it doesn't.

```
db.pets.find({},{"_id":0})
```

Instead, it returns the *pets* in the order that they were inserted. My conclusion is that I lack a fundamental understanding of how indices work. Can someone please help me to understand?

Comment: db.pets.find({},{"_id":0}).sort({'name':1}) will work .You can use sort() to specify the order in which the query returns matching documents. Check these link for more info https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor-sort or https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-with-a-single-field-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is misunderstanding about how indexes work.**

Indexes don't change the output of a query but the way query is processed by the database engine. So `db.pets.find({},{"_id":0})` will always  return the documents in natural order irrespective of whether there is an index or not.

Indexes will be used only when you make use of them in your query. Thus,
`db.pets.find({name : "My pet's name"},{"_id":0})` and `db.pets.find({}, {_id : 0}).sort({name : 1})` will use the `{name : 1}` index.

You should run [`explain`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on your queries to check if indexes are being used or not.

You may want to refer the documentation on how indexes work.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/